# Final Fantasy I weapons

Tags: final-fantasy

What are the best (most damage) weapons for each of the characters in the original Final Fantasy?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*These answers assume vanilla/classic original Final Fantasy. I've honestly never played any of the ports/reissues to know what's availiable in the bonus content or if anything has changed*

**Black Belt/Master:** Bare Hands

**Everyone Else:** Masamune

Sadly, you only get one Masamune, so give the Masamune to your White or Red Mage/Wizard, and for the rest, use these 'Second Best' options, listed roughly in order of 'who not to give a Masamune to' if someone else in the party can use it, from least deserving (has the best alternative) to most.

**Fighter/Knight:** Excalibur

**Thief/Ninja:** Katana

**Black Mage/Wizard:** Cat Claw

**White Mage/Wizard:** Thor's Hammer

**Red Mage/Wizard:** Defense Sword

Comment: Why give it to a mage, which will use magics instead of normal attack?

Comment: @Lo'oris: In the original FFI, mages are pretty much *required* to attack "normally". Magic is very restricted: you only have a certain number of casts per magic level (of course, higher magic levels allow fewer casts), and the only way to recover is by resting is by using a cottage (which cost 2000 gil each) or going to an inn. You can't just nuke everything out of orbit and then drink a potion to recover your MP whenever you run low.

Comment: @Michael: oh thx, I guess I didn't play it enough to remember that

Comment: @MichaelMadsen that's not counting the many magical items in the game, which you can `use` to cast up to medium-level spells (e.g. `LIT2`, `HEAL`) without spending a single MP.

Answer (score 6):

[This website](http://www.kuponut.com/games/ff1/weapons_chart.html) has a chart of weapons and which characters can equip them. The Masamune has the highest attack stat (56) and can be equipped by all characters, so I would assume it's the strongest.

The Xcalbrer is the second strongest weapon with an attack stat of 45, and can only be equipped by Knights. The Katana has an attack stat of 33 and can be equipped by Ninjas.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if there are any magic attack stats on weapons, so maybe there is a better option for mages / wizards.

Comment: Weapons don't have any benefit to magic stats in the original Final Fantasy, though some, like Thor's Hammer have indispensable On Use effects in combat.

Comment: Is that a complete list? I thought there was a Murasame or something like that. And I am pretty sure there was something stronger than the Masmune. Also I did not realize anyone could use the Masmune... I never went to get it on my 4 Black Mage playthrough.

Comment: @Kevin if you're going to link a website, please provide a summery of the data it contains, there is no way to guarantee that link won't go stale.

Comment: I must be going nuts, I could have sworn I remember my ninja dual wielding the Masamune and the Murasame in the original NES version of the game. All sources point to me having faulty memory.

Comment: The 'Murasame' in later releases was originally simply called the Katana I believe. And you certainly didn't dual wield it as there was no dual wielding in the original Final Fantasy.

Comment: Apparently it's been a while since I've played. It was Edge in Final Fantasy IV (US II) that would have been doing the dual 
wielding.